# Is it possible to check h2o version of the model saved in file?

Tags: r, h2o

I would like to check h2o version assigned to a model saved in file.
Is it possible in current h2o editions (I have eg. *3.29.0.4930*)?

I can't find it in the messages written during `h2o.loadModel()` in R console unless there is a mismatch in h2o versions: "Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = page, : ERROR MESSAGE: Found version 3.14.0.3, but running version 3.29.0.4930"

Can I access it before loading model using h2o?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the binary model file with a text editor, you will see that the first line would display the H2O version it was saved in.

For example, using unix based command `head -n 1 your_model_file` returns

```
?   3.32.0.3 ...
```

Comment: Good idea! I suppose there is no function for this in h2o library.

Comment: Not that I know at the moment. But opening it as text should work fine

Comment: It would be good practice to save your files with version numbers or by folders so you know